# How to compute total within sum of square in hierarchical clustering

Tags: r

I read several textbook and online tutorials about clustering algorithms. In K-mean algorithm, when you run `kmean()` the information of `total within sum of square` is included. But we run`hclust()`in agglomerative hierarchical clustering, we can not find this information. So is that possible to compute `TWSS` for `hclust()`? Or is is reasonable to calculate the `TWSS` in `hclust()`?

The original data set is something like this:

```
1   -1.6768555093  -1.33937070  1.246858892  1.23171108 2.186761
2   -3.0832450282   1.28841533  0.286807651  1.54836547 3.494282
3   -1.4664760903   0.80289181  1.940444140  1.84226142 3.543522
4   -3.1109618863   0.32801815  -0.497680172 2.54236639 2.501975
5   -2.7603333486   0.49249130  1.041125723  1.75577604 2.868788
6   -4.3145154475   -2.01808802 1.227723818  0.09547962 2.570594
7   -1.6097707596   0.25391455  2.978627043  0.07428535 4.510882
```

Below is my code. In here, `minClusters = 1`, `maxClusters = 10`

```
hierarchy_mod <- hclust(Eucli_dis,method = "complete")
memb <- cutree(hierarchy_mod,minClusters:maxClusters)
memb_DT <- data.table(memb)
```

I got the result of a matrix and transfer it to data.table:

```
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   1: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
   2: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2  2
   3: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2  2
   4: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
   5: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2  2
...
```

The problem for me now is I don't know how to compute the `TWSS` in this scenario. I checked on-line tutorial and text books but in `hclust()`, no one calculate the TWSS...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWSS is useful in comparing different results using kmeans because the starting configuration is usually random so different runs can give different results. That does not happen in hierarchical clustering since the cluster process is deterministic. But you can easily write R commands to compute it for any cluster result. First we need to make a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(4242)
x <- matrix(rnorm(125), 25, 5)
x.dist <- dist(x)
x.clus <- hclust(x.dist, metho="complete")
plot(x.clus)
x.grps <- cutree(x.clus, 3:5)
```

We are clustering 25 rows (cases) by 5 columns (variables). We will look at solutions involving 3 to 5 clusters. We can use the scale() function to compute the sums of squares by cluster and then sum them:

```
x.SS <- aggregate(x, by=list(x.grps[, 1]), function(x) sum(scale(x,
        scale=FALSE)^2))
x.SS
SS <- rowSums(x.SS[, -1]) # Sum of squares for each cluster
TSS <- sum(x.SS[, -1])  # Total (within) sum of squares
```

You will have to run this code for x.grps[, 1], x.grps[, 2], and x.grps[, 3]. Or make it into a function and use `apply()` to get them all:

```
TSS <- function(x, g) {
    sum(aggregate(x, by=list(g), function(x) sum(scale(x, 
        scale=FALSE)^2))[, -1])
}
TSS.all <- apply(x.grps, 2, function(g) TSS(x, g))
TSS.all
```

Comment: Thank you for the resolution. Your aggregate function gives me an fresh air, I never used it before. One more question, if the second argument of `cutree` function is `1:10`, are there any way that I can automated the second part(x.ss to tss) in such that I do not need to run the second part 10 times. Thank you!

Comment: See the above edits for one way to do that by creating a function to compute TSS.

Comment: Hi, I am little confused about the TSS function, although the function works. when I input two values `x` ,`g`, like `TSS(train, memb)` (in here, `train` is my original dataset and `memb` is my `cutree` result object), the R throw me an error. But when I run `TSS` and `TSS.all` together, it successfully returns the result. Could you please explain more about this? Thank you!

Comment: The TSS function assumes that g defines a single column, e.g. memb[, 1].